# Example of a non measurable function.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{M})$ a measurable space. If $f\colon X \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a non $\mathcal{M}$-measurable function, is it possible that $|f|$ is a measurable function?

As far as I know ,if $f\colon X \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a measurable function then $|f|$ is measurable and in addition to that it exists a measurable function $\alpha\colon X \longrightarrow D(0,1)\subset\mathbb{C}$ such that $f=|f| \alpha$. I tried to build an example by choosing $\alpha$ to be the characteristic function of a non measurable set, but I cannot guaranteed that $|f|$ is measurable in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for $f$ to be non-measurable and $|f|$ to be measurable:

Let $N$ be a non-measurable set, and define $f(x)=1$ if $x\in N$, $f(x)=-1$ if $x\not\in N$. Then $f$ is not measurable, but $|f|$ is the constant function $1$, hence is measurable.