# Clarification about non-measureable function

Tags: measure-theory

Let $N\in \mathcal{A}$
be a non-measurable set, and define $f(x)=1$
if $x∈N
, f(x)=−1
 $if $x∉N
.$

Then $f$
is not measurable, but $|f|$
is the constant function 1
, hence is measurable.

I read this anaswer in the post [Example of a non measurable function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2515702/example-of-a-non-measurable-function)

Let $x\in N$ $f$ is not measurable since $f^{-1}(x)=N \notin \mathcal{A}$. (please correct me in case I am wrong).

Why $|f|$ is mesuarable?

$|f(x)|=1 \forall x $ implies $|f|^{-1}=N$ but $N \notin \mathcal{A}$ .

Where am I getting wrong ?

Comment: Kindly use more descriptive titles to increase utility of this question to other users of MSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim that $|f|^{-1} = N$ is false.

Let $g \equiv |f|$ so that $g$ is the constant function equal to one everywhere.

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$.
If $E$ does not contain $1$, then $g^{-1}(E) = \emptyset$ since $g$ only maps points to one.
Otherwise, $g^{-1}(E) = X$ (the set of all points in the domain) since $g$ maps any point to one.
Since any $\sigma$-algebra must have $\emptyset$ and $X$ as elements, $g$ is measurable for any choice of $\sigma$-algebra.